# looping on array throws: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

**Edit: Issue was with environment. Terminal restart made things work again.**

I was given an assignment, write a function get_name(names) , call it with [{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"}] and do an action with the name.

My code is:

```
def get_name(names):
     for name in names:
        print name
```

and when I call it with

```
get_name([{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"}])
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "test.py", line 2, in get_name
for name in names:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I read all links regarding this error on the first 5 google result pages and a few more directly on stackoverflow - none give a hind to the issue I'm having.

Comment: I can't get your error to occur. `>>> get_name([{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"}])` gives me 
`{'name': 'one'}` and 
`{'name': 'two'}`

Comment: @PokemonGirl3 the code you provided seems okay from my end too. Try pasting in and rerunning what you just posted?

Comment: how are you running this, from terminal / jupyter / spyder?

Comment: From terminal. I figured if it works for you it must be a problem with the environment somehow. exiting and entering python didn't help, restarting the terminal solved the issue and the code works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of python are you using?
I have python 3.6.4 and when i try exactly your code i have

```
{'name': 'one'}
{'name': 'two'}
```

as output

Comment: If the code works for you it must have been the environment. I restarted the terminal and it started working.